# No exact matches in call to instance method error message in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I never get this before, What is the meaning of this error message in Swift:

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)'

Here is my code block:

```
var request: NSMutableURLRequest? = nil
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(
            with: request,
            completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                  /// ...
                })
            })
task.resume()
```

#### Bug Report

Reported via feedbackassistant.apple.com: **FB7717686**

**Note: The Error still exists in the Xcode Version 14.3 on 2023, May 1**

Comment: The error message can be MISLEADING! For me I was passing **two** optionals as arguments for my function — while both needed to be non-optional. **If** I did correct one of the inputs then the error would instead be something meaningful: "Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'". The compiler is able to show the correct error message when a single parameter is passed incorrectly. Yet when it's two, the compiler gives you a misleading/hard to interpret message. FWIW some answers point to some other misleading error. So your case might be diff

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Why Xcode Yelling?

Maybe the message text seems a little bit **self-explanatory** but because [Xcode](https://apps.apple.com/tr/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) does not precisely point to the parameter itself, a little bit hard to figure out the first time.

Xcode is yelling because the method wants to see **exact parameter types** on the method call, that is easy.

### Solution for the Question:

```
var request: URLRequest? = nil

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(
            with: request!,
            completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                })
            })
task.resume()
```

Just used the **[URLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest)** instead of the [NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest).

### A SwiftUI Case

Let's assume this is your UI:

```
        ZStack() {
            Image(systemName: "photo")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .background(Color.green)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(12)
            Text(getToday())
                .font(.headline)
            }
        }
```

And this is the method that you're calling in the Text(...):

```
    func getToday() -> Any?
    {
        let now = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: now)
        return components.day

    }
```

**Solution**

In the example above solution would be changing the **Any?** to a **String** type.

### A NSURL Case

```
if let url = NSURL(String: "http://example-url.com/picture.png") {
  // ...
}
```

**Solution**

```
if let url = URL(String: "http://example-url.com/picture.png") {
  // ...
}
```

## ℹ️ No exact matches in call

## to instance method '* * *'

This is a **general error message** for using the wrong type in the method calls. That's why I added here to help others.

I hope this answer will help some of you guys.

Best.

Comment: You might want to file a bug report with Apple. Surely the diagnostic could be better than this.

Comment: Thank you @matt, I reported via https://feedbackassistant.apple.com.

Comment: The error still appears almost 2 years later in Xcode 12.4 in the same confusing way: I was using `session.dataTask(with: url)` but hadn't changed the surrounding function to pass the url yet (`url` was undeclared) and that's the error I got, even though `dataTask(with:) exists.

Answer (score 10):

I was using `dataTask` with URL, but I was unwrapping the URL as `NSURL`, and that is why it was giving me an error.

I was doing this:

```
if let url = NSURL(String: "http://myyrl.com/filename.jpg") {
      //my code
}
```

What fixed the error was replacing `NSURL` with `URL`:

```
if let url = URL(String: "http://myyrl.com/filename.jpg") {
      //my code 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's about Xcode and it's a general error message. It can cause in so many situations. Best.

Answer (score 5):

If you're getting this error in a **`Text`** element, try **wrapping** your value in **`String(describing: value)`**. Fixed my case.

```swift
Text("Leading text \(String(describing: value))")
```

<sub>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67451803/1678614)</sub>

Comment: Might not be the exact answer to the question, but in general is a way to workaround this. Often it is just an unwrapped optional, and this way you will discover

Answer (score 3):

Xcode gives this error when you add `SKPaymentQueue` methods (such as `SKPaymentQueue.default().add()` to your code before making the current class conform to the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` protocol.

Just make your class conform to the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` protocol to solve this error if this is the case.

Comment: My class was missing `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`, this was the only helpful comment, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also check if the `url` is the `actual url` and not a `String`

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error
```