# How to string interpolate a generic type

Tags: swiftui

Looking to pass in a generic type `Value` that can be represented in a string in a `Text("\(value)"`

Now literally the only two possible data types would be `String` and `Double` ( or some other number type) so maybe I'm going down the wrong rabbit hole here so I'm open for suggestions in the best path to take..

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do..

```
struct AnswerView<Value: ExpressibleByStringLiteral>: View {
   let value: Value
   var body: some View {
       Text("Your answer is \(value)") //<--Error: No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `String(describing:)`:

```
Text("Your answer is \(String(describing: value))")
```

or (very similarly):

```
struct AnswerView<Value: CustomStringConvertible>: View {
   let value: Value
   var body: some View {
    Text("Your answer is \(value.description)")
   }
}
```